# asio.ssl error "shutdown while in init" on Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: openssl, asio, raspberry-pi4, ubuntu-20.04

I know that this problem probably covers the topics of three different stack exchange sites but I figured this is the closest one.

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4. There I run a discord bot server based on this [C++ library](https://github.com/yourWaifu/sleepy-discord). It seems to use another library called [asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/). I compile it with `cmake` and `make` without any problems. When running the application I get this error:

```
[2020-04-30 11:15:45] [connect] Successful connection
[2020-04-30 11:15:45] [error] handle_transport_init received error: TLS handshake failed
[2020-04-30 11:15:45] [info] asio async_shutdown error: asio.ssl:336462231 (shutdown while in init)
```

I have the identical code running without problems on my Ubuntu 18.04 PC.

Things I've tried:

- **Look up the error**: Others have stated that this is either a bug that needs to get fixed or that something is wrong with openssl. All of those forum posts are quite old though.
- **Reinstall openssl**

At last I think that the problem has either to do with Ubuntu 20.04 which is pretty new or the Raspberry Pi 4. Either way, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: There appears to be a major issue with 20.04 and SSL. See probably related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231799/certificate-error-after-upgrade-to-20-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231799/certificate-error-after-upgrade-to-20-04

Comment: I got my `curl` and `wget` SSL errors solved by following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level It did not fix my `pip` SSL error.